# Getting a word count frequency out of a page field

Tags: solr

SOLR reports the term occurrence for terms over all the documents. I am having trouble making a query that returns the term occurrence in a specific page field called, documentPageId.

I don't know how to issue a proper SOLR query that returns a word count for a paragraph of text such as the term "amplifier" for a field. For some reason it only returns.

The things I've tried only return a count for 1 occurrence of the term even though I see the term in the paragraph more than just once.

I've tried faceting on the field, "contents"

http://localhost:8983/solr/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=standard&facet=on&facet.field=documentPageId&facet.query=amplifier&facet.sort=lex&facet.missing=on&facet.method=count

```
<lst name="facet_counts">
<lst name="facet_queries">
<int name="amplifier">21</int>
</lst>
<lst name="facet_fields">
<lst name="documentPageId">
<int name="49667.1">1</int>
<int name="49667.10">1</int>
<int name="49667.11">1</int>
<int name="49667.12">1</int>
<int name="49667.13">1</int>
<int name="49667.14">1</int>
<int name="49667.15">1</int>
<int>0</int>
</lst>
</lst>
<lst name="facet_dates"/>
<lst name="facet_ranges"/>
</lst>
</response>
```

In schema.xml:

In solrconfig.xml:

```
   <str name="facet.field">filewrapper</str>
   <str name="facet.field">caseNumber</str>
   <str name="facet.field">pageNumber</str>
   <str name="facet.field">documentId</str>
   <str name="facet.field">contents</str>
   <str name="facet.query">documentId</str>
   <str name="facet.query">caseNumber</str>
   <str name="facet.query">pageNumber</str>
  <str name="facet.field">documentPageId</str>
   <str name="facet.query">contents</str>
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **TermVectorsComponent** to get term frequency for a give document. Facets won't get you there.

Please read the wiki at [TermVectorCompoment](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermVectorComponent).

The option **tv.tf** will return the term frequency for a given field on per document basis. Make sure the field that you are interested in has the termVectors enabled (`termVectors="true"` ) .

```xml
<field name="pageField" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" />
```

**Note:** Enabling term vectors will increase the index size & the time required to index. So be wary of this and do benchmark before & after.

Comment: Great! This worked well. However, to speed up the query, how can I limit it to a specific term inside the document page. It is returning all the terms and their frequency count.

Comment: I guess by `document page` you mean a field in Solr. Right now if you check the implementation of Solr **TermVectorComponent** it uses Lucene 'IndexReader.getTermFreqVector' internally & there is no meaningful way to get TermVector Information only for a set of terms in field. But since the cost of computing most of term vectors is incurred during index time, it should be faster to retrieve, one way to restrict is to get it only for a particular `field`, `document` & perhaps just `tf`, but it depends on your application's design & usage.

Comment: Looks like you have to do 2 queries. THe first query for getting the term frequency in each page, and the second query to get the offsets. Doesn't look like you can do both.

Comment: Term Frequency Query [link]http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?fl=score,documentPageId,termfreq%28contents,amplifiers%29,contents&defType=func&q=tf%28contents,amplifiers%29&f.contents.tv.offsets=true

Comment: Term Offset Query [link]http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?fl=documentPageId&q=documentPageId:49667.9&qt=tvrh&tv.tf=true&tv.fl=contents&tv.offsets=true    The problem with the second query is that it gives the offsets for all the terms it indexed. You can't limit it to just the term "amplifiers"?

Comment: @mailboat can you please provide a sample query to count occurrences of words in 'text' field of an indexed document that has been set up as you mentioned. I am using Solr 4.1 and having trouble to construct query based on TermVectorComponent to get desired response. Thanks